# My application icons dissapeared after restoring (from backup), how to get them back?

Tags: windows-7, backup, taskbar, icons, start-menu

My laptop harddisk crashed. However, since I use a backup solution (HP Autonomy), I managed to restore most of the documents and files that had been backed up, after reinstalling the operating system, i.e. Windows 7 Professional, 64-bit on the new hard-disk.

However, I realized just now that I was backing up even application data, and even that has been restored. Since my backup restoration took much longer (about half a day), I had already reinstalled my software packages. After the backup restoration was complete, I noticed that I can no longer see icons for many applications. The icons for these applications were visible in the taskbar and the start menu earlier, but now I see generic "missing icon" symbol.

Here are some screen shots. Right clicking on the icons to bring up their properties, I see that the shortcuts have "(1)", "(2)" suffixes, indicating that either during installation or data restore, duplicates were created.

[image: Startmenu icon mess]

[image: Taskbar]

**How can I solve/fix this issue and get of the application icons to show properly ?**

*PS> I love the Windows Classic look-n-feel and find that it has better performance, so don't be surprised and suspect that this is not a Windows 7 setup. Just to clarify.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to try:

1. [Rebuild Windows Icon Cache](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/rebuild-the-icon-cache-windows), either by simply deleting the DB or following the directions for CMD use.
2. You wrote "I love the Windows Classic look-n-feel," so I assume you use Classic Shell and Classic Start Menu, which has a setting to "pre-cache" icons. If that cache is corrupted, it might need to be reloaded. In the *Classic Start Menu* settings dialog, on the *General Behavior* tab of the dialog, uncheck "Pre-cache icons". After rebooting, it can be turned on again if desired.

Another possibility is that the actual *file association* with applications have been lost, which may take a bit of work to fix for each application; use the *Open with..." dialogs to fix that.

Comment: Step 1 worked wonderfully well, and all icons are restored. Noted the information in point #2 as well. Does turning off "pre-caching" (I presume that's what that setting checkbox means) have any effect on performance ?

Comment: Classic Shell hints indicate pre-caching speeds startup, though I have  not tested running with it off [it is *on* by default].